Non-Error promise rejection captured with value: Timeout
I've recently integrated invisible recaptcha v3 in my react application.
After the deployment of my new release I'm facing an error in my Sentry dashboard -
UnhandledRejection: Non-Error promise rejection captured with value: Timeout
I've used the docs for integration - https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3
Note that I'm loading the reCaptcha script using webpack for my whole project but only the login page is using the recaptcha based checking (token generation + token transfer to backend) but the users for which I'm facing this seems to already logged in and interacting with other routes of the application.

By Aagam Vadecha’s blog

When an error arises within a promise, it gets rejected and calls the reject() function. Unhandled promise rejections imply that when a promise is rejected, it is not handled. It is unhandled because nothing deals with the rejection.

no code is handling the promise rejection in the function.
To handle promise rejections specifically, we can use the .catch() handler method. A more popular option is to wrap the promise call in a try-catch block.
Or Filtering error via sdk configurations Filtering error event by using ignoreErrors and BeforeSend method.
As per this sentry discussion Forum about the error handling
use the ignoreErrors option to filter out errors that match a certain pattern.

Sentry.init({
    dsn:__MY_DSN__,
      ignoreErrors:[
       "Non-Error exception captured",
       "Non-Error promise rejection captured"
      ]
    })


beforeSend to drop these events, by looking at the error name and returning null if it matches the error you're describing.
